# Get Identity value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have following situation.

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO test1(val) SELECT 1

INSERT INTO test2(val) SELECT 2
```

How can i get test1 identity value? Consider that **read committed snapshot** is database isolation level, so insert into these table is permitted from another session, while transaction is opened.

Comment: What you mean by "test1 identity value"?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i have identity column in test1 table, and want to get it's value after row affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO test1(val) SELECT 1
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO test2(val) SELECT 2
```

Comment: Problem is  that, I want to get identity value after both insert statements will performe

Comment: @tungi How is that a problem. Just do the last `scope_identity()` then.

Comment: Sorry, I have made mistake in post, second insert is in another table

Comment: @tungi nothing changes.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson consider that there is procedure whout out parametr and select statement in it.
CREATE PROC tes_proc
AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO test1(val) SELECT 1
 
 INSERT INTO test2(val) SELECT 2
END

Question is how to get identity coulumn value from test1 table, after procedure run?

Comment: @tungi Well, you have a select statement in it. `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. And it works just fine as you can see in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c958c/1)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson with select statement everything is clear, what about without it?  My task is to have one main transaction and run two procedures under it, first will be test_proc(which only inserts and returns nothing) and second proc_test_proc_getIdent(which will return identity value from test1 table)

Comment: @tungi Ok, sorry. Not possible. You could get the current identity before calling the procedure and after you can query the table for all rows with a value greater than the saved value and then you know that one of the rows returned was your row. So if you have a way to distinguish your row from rows added by other connections then it might be possible for you to build something.